# How many potentials are there in total? Is this the more complete way of writing the first law of thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, potential

The first law is usually given as: $dE = dQ + dW = TdS + PdV$

Sometimes the chemical potential energy is also included.
But you can include way more potentials. These are some that I came up with:

$$ E = TdS + pdV + \gamma dA + F dl + V_e dq + V_g dm + \mu dN  + \sigma_{ij}\mathrm{d}\varepsilon_{ij}$$

Where

1. $T$ is the temperature
2. $p$ is the pressure
3. $\gamma $ is the surface tension
4. $F$ is the force on an elastic band
5. $V_e$ is the voltage
6. $V_g$ is the gravitational potential
7. $\mu$ is the chemical potential
8. $\sigma_{ij}$ is the stress tensor

...
..
Are there more potentials? Is there a way to unify them all more and more neatly?

I don't mean the derived potentials like Gibbs, helmholtz etc.

Comment: Why do you write it in terms of differentials?  What if the change is finite and the intermediate states are not equilibrium states?

Comment: See this for the four thermodynamic potentials: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/thepot.html#c1

Comment: @Chet Miller isn't this always writting in this form? What do you mean exactly?

Comment: @Bob D thank you for your answer, but I don't mean the 'derived' potentials from the existing potentials

Comment: What I mean is $\Delta E=Q-W$, constrained by the 2nd law $\Delta S=\int{\frac{dQ_{rev}}{T}}$ for a reversible path only.

Comment: As far as I’m aware the first and second laws are completely independent of one another. Neither “constrains” the other